# How to install Java EE?

Tags: java, maven, installation

I'm trying to learn how to use the EE version of Java and it's my first time downloading the files and other components just as Maven etc and have the proper environment variables set correctly. But when it comes to download the file of Java EE itself, it doesn't make sense to me at all. It's basically a .zip file and from its installation instructions it basically says that simply unzipping the file and none further instructions after. I tried using experimenting the sample projects in Netbeans and it seems to be working fine but I just want to consult everyone what is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is Java JDK downloaded and unziped, then you have to set environment variables JAVA_HOME and add path to your java bin folder in PATH and configure your IDE. I use Eclipse for it.

Comment: yup i have the Java JDK installed and EE SDK unzipped. As for JAVA_HOME path value i have it set to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25` do i have to edit the path for the java bin folder as well like you said? :)

Comment: you just need to add path to your java bin to PATH after ;